# Tcl/Tk GUI interface for C++ library

Tags: c++, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a C++ library that we're using to override some functions for testing. However, we just have it set up to prompt from the command line.

I'm looking to create a GUI for it to use as the prompt rather than command line.

I've been looking into Tcl/Tk, but I'm not quite sure if it can do what I'd like.  Is it possible to use the Tcl/Tk wrapper to stylize my library functions?

Can I just include Tcl/Tk in my C++ code somehow, so that I call those functions right inside my library?

Comment: Do you really mean to mention "Tlc", or did you mean "Tcl"?

Comment: Yep, you're completely correct. I've edited the post - Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to wrap your C++ functions with swig and call them from Tcl, see  [this intro](http://www.swig.org/papers/Tcl98/TclChap.html), then you can use Tk to create a GUI for your input parameters and/or displaying your results.

Answer (score 1):

The two mechanisms to consider for this are [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.1/HTML/Tcl.html) and [critcl in C++ mode](http://www2.tcl.tk/8403). The former is probably easier to get going with as you already have the C++ code, and the latter produces more natural (more “Tcl-ish”) language embeddings.

Once you've got your library connected up, the first thing to do is probably to write a little test suite (using [`tcltest`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tcltest.htm), a standard package supplied with Tcl) so that you know that things are working. (That saves a lot of heartache and hair-tearing later on!) If your code is working fine, you'll probably have a good enough test suite within a day or two. Then hook it up to your GUI (Tk is indeed good for that), which can be written safe in the knowledge that it's using a business logic layer that's working fine. I encourage you to avoid putting any GUI code in your C++ code if you can; it's far better to produce a clean interface without entanglements. (OK, it's not always possible to avoid, especially if you're doing heavy visualization, but it's a lot more work…)

Comment: You also might consider using [ffidl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1197), which can call DLL functions directly.

Comment: I realize this is nearly nine years old, but may I ask if this is still a viable method? Specifically, could one use C, the SQLite C amalgamation, and SWIG with Tcl to use Tk for a GUI; or should one use the Tcl interface to SQLite? Is Tk even a good GUI any longer? I've been building a desktop-like application using a web browser extension as the UI, and the native-messaging API to communicate with C compiled with SQLite. If the browser is dropped, can a Tk GUI play audio or video and display an image? Available information appears conflicting and limited. Thank you.

Comment: I must've been looking in the wrong places because there are many books on this. It appears the most recent is from 2012-13 but one by the creator of Tcl is from 2010. I was looking on archive.org for old books because I thought this was an old language but apparently it is quite active.